# Need help in sql Query.neo

Tags: sql

[image: TABLE DETAIL]

In this table there are three colum and in need the value for of data which are lesser than code = 28,this is my query

```
SELECT value,code,date
FROM table
order by date,vchcode
```

but when i ad where clouse like

```
SELECT value,code,date
FROM table
where code < 28
order by date,vchcode
```

is only shows 2 row with code 26 and 27... i need 26,27 and 32.. and table colums are variable its not fix..

Comment: You require to have `lesser than code = 28` and have `WHERE code < 28` (that is correct). But you actually expected a code __greater than 28__, namely `32` ?

Comment: Yes sir becouse date of code 28 is higer than date of 32 .. i know its complicated that is why i need help.

Comment: Yes sir becouse date of code 28 is higer than date of 32 .. i know its complicated that is why i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wnat to take the date into account -- what you really want are all rows before the *date* of the row with code `28`.

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT t.value, t.code, t.date
FROM table t
WHERE date < (SELECT date FROM table t2 WHERE t2.code = 28)
ORDER BY t.date, t.vchcode
```

Comment: sir thank you it was help full i had to change t2.code < 28 to t2.code = 28 but i got my answer and sir i need to sum value colum but i cant i get error number 3122.. can you help me with that.

Comment: @KushTiwari . . . Nothing in this question references "error number" "3122".  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: sir i need values on basis of < code.. as per your query if i put  (code < 35) it wont show data for code 31 becouse they are on same date..  and if i remove date variable it wont show data for code 28...

Comment: @KushTiwari . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with a clear explanation of what you want to happen with ties.  You might just want `where date <= ( . . . ) and code <> 28`; however, it is not clear if that is the right logic.